# Angular error "expected to not be in angular zone but it is"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing a web app in Angular, and I keep getting this error popping up in the Chrome console:
[image]

Up until now I didn't bother doing anything about it because it didn't seem to affect the behaviour of the application, but recently I added a new feature which causes this error to pop up thousands upon thousands of times while the app is open, and this is causing Chrome's memory usage to skyrocket.

The research I did on this suggested that I do the following:

- Add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.8.29/zone.js"></script>` to the index.html file.
- Remove `import 'Zone.js'` from Polyfills.ts.

Neither of which have worked.

The main application page has a number of async functions which all iterate in a loop in order to get data from the backend which is required to keep the page up to date without having to refresh the page.

If you need any other information let me know, and thanks for any help you can give me :)

```js
async GetFriendsAsync() {
    while (true) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/getfriends", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "ID": this.GetSessionValueNullSafe("ID")
        })
      }).then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      });

      let stringFriends = response.split("<[SePaRaToR]>");
      if (stringFriends[0] == '') {
        continue;
      }

      this.friends = stringFriends.sort((a, b) => {
        if (parseInt(JSON.parse(a).ID) > parseInt(JSON.parse(b).ID)) {
          return 1;
        }
        else if (parseInt(JSON.parse(a).ID) < parseInt(JSON.parse(b).ID)) {
          return -1;
        }
        else {
          return 0;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

```js
async GetMessagesAsync() {
    while (true) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      
      if (this.selectedFriendString == '') {
        continue;
      }

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/getmessages", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "userID": this.GetSessionValueNullSafe("ID"),
          "friendID": JSON.parse(this.selectedFriendString).ID
        })
      }).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.text();
        }
        else {
          alert("Something went wrong when trying to get messages!");
          return "";
        }
      });

      this.messages = response.split("<[SePaRaToR]>");
    }
  }
```

```js
async GetFriendRequestsAsync() {
    while (true) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/getfriendrequests", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "ID": this.GetSessionValueNullSafe("ID")
        })
      }).then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      });

      if (response.split("<[SePaRaToR]>")[0] == '') {
        this.friendRequests = [];
        continue;
      }

      let requests = response.split("<[SePaRaToR]>").map((item) => { return JSON.parse(item); });
      let friend_requests = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/getuser/id", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            "ID": requests[i].senderID
          })
        }).then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        });

        friend_requests.push(JSON.stringify(response));
      }

      friend_requests = friend_requests.sort((a, b) => {
        if (parseInt(JSON.parse(a).ID) > parseInt(JSON.parse(b).ID)) {
          return 1;
        }
        else if (parseInt(JSON.parse(a).ID) < parseInt(JSON.parse(b).ID)) {
          return -1;
        }
        else {
          return 0;
        }
      });
      this.friendRequests = friend_requests;
    }
  }
```

```js
async HeartbeatAsync() {
    var response: string;

    while (true) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));

      response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/heartbeat", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "ID": this.GetSessionValueNullSafe("ID")
        })
      }).then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      });
    }
  }
```

```js
async GetUserOnlineState(userID: string) {
    var response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/getuseractivestate", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "ID": userID
      })
    }).then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    });

    let state = response.active === "1";
    response = null;
    return state;
  }
```

Above are all the async functions that are iterated. `GetUserOnlineState()` is called by the html template here:

```html
<div *ngIf="GetUserOnlineState(Json.parse(friend).ID)" class="online-icon"></div>
<div *ngIf="!GetUserOnlineState(Json.parse(friend).ID)" class="offline-icon"></div>
```

When I comment out the HTML above the memory usage is relatively stable, its only when `GetUserOnlineState()` is being called that the memory usage increases continuously.

Comment: can you share your code of some of those async functions. zone is basically monkey patching to all events in the browser. So you might have some code where you want to run outside the zone, but for some reason indicated by the error it is still with in the zone.

Comment: also you can add a breakpoint in the browser for the line, and look at the stacktrace, then you can find the part of your code who causes the issue.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I've added the async functions above, hope that helps. I'll see what I can find with the breakpoints as well.

Comment: I can see why you would get bombarded with messages. not sure why the message but for sure due to binding functions in the template they will be triggered every time the ui redraws. So basically in any event. I would advice you to use HttpClient form angular instead and get the results as observables then you can use an async pipe for this. https://angular.io/guide/http .For your heartbeat you can put the http request behind an interval operator from rxjs. instead of running an `while( true )`

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen Thanks, I'll look into this :)

Comment: What stands out for me is that you call those functions from the template. That’s a huge issue in this case because angular will execute these methods on every change detection cycle. I’d recommend to completely rethink this approach and  use Observables and the built-in HttpClient. You might even want to consider using a websocket instead of polling with setTimeout.(edit: I didn’t yet see Henriks comment when I started typing this.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen for explaining why this was happening :)

I fixed the issue by calling the `GetUserOnlineState()` function in a loop like the others, rather than calling it from the template. This fixed the issue with memory usage.

As for the HttpClient approach, I will look into this at it does seem like a better approach, but for now this has fixed the issue. Thanks for your help @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen and @MikeOne :)